# Visual Studio 2013 no longer displays TFS output

Tags: git, visual-studio-2013, tfs

I've been developing a project using VS 2013, connecting to a TFS server that I reach thru a VPN connection. There was always a "Source Control - Team Foundation" item in the "Show output from" dropdown in VS.

At some point, while VS was running, the VPN connection was lost. I have since re-connected it, but something is not right. I have restarted VS, reconnected to TFS, and can see the Source Control Explorer, Pending Changes, and other TFS things -- but there is no longer a "Source Control - Team Foundation" entry in the "Show output from" dropdown.

The gobbledygook for TFS in the solution file I've opened is still there. I can do things like check out a file; that would normally display something if I choose the TFS entry from the "Show output from" dropdown, but I see nothing now.

[Some additional info that I think is not relevant] 
I had been using Git to maintain a local copy of things. The only thing in the "Show output from" dropdown had been "Source Control - Git". When I opened a solution, the connection to TFS in the Team Explorer went away -- it said "Offline", and TFS was not available.

To try to fix things, I moved the .git directory somewhere else (so VS won't see it), and now the "Show output from" dropdown doesn't have anything in it. I can now open the solution with the only thing wrong being that I can't see the TFS output by selecting it from the "Show output from" dropdown.
[End irrelevant other info]

Where is the info about what should be in that dropdown maintained?

What can I do? (I could try deleting the solutionName.suo file but that would lose a lot of useful info.) Would a repair reinstall perhaps help?

I could try using an MSDN Support Incident but I'm trying this first. Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: My own answer can't be marked as the accepted answer for two days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inexplicably, the solution seemed to be to pick a source-controlled file and edit it. Even though that should be the same as doing "Check Out for Edit" in Source Control Explorer, doing "Check Out for Edit" didn't display anything and left the "Show output from" dropdown empty.

Making a change to a file caused "filename.cs has been automatically checked out for editing." in the output window, and now the "Show output from" dropdown has "Source Control - Team Foundation" in it -- as it had always had before.

It's quite a mystery to me but the problem seems to be solved.